# How do I call a SQL Server stored procedure from PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a large CSV file and I want to execute a stored procedure for each line.

What is the best way to execute a stored procedure from PowerShell?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This answer was pulled from http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3683181

This same example can be used for any adhoc queries. Let us execute the stored procedure “sp_helpdb” as shown below.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=HOME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_helpdb"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

Comment: Note: if you're calling a stored procedure that has parameters, you should also set the command type: `$sqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure`.

Comment: For adding parameters: `$SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", "$param") | Out-Null`.

Comment: why do your return dataset.tables[0]   what is int the zero index

Answer (score 11):

Here is a function that I use (slightly redacted).  It allows input and output parameters.  I only have uniqueidentifier and varchar types implemented, but any other types are easy to add.  If you use parameterized stored procedures (or just parameterized sql...this code is easily adapted to that), this will make your life a lot easier.

To call the function, you need a connection to the SQL server (say $conn),

> $res=exec-storedprocedure -storedProcName 'stp_myProc' -parameters @{Param1="Hello";Param2=50} -outparams @{ID="uniqueidentifier"} $conn
>
> *retrieve proc output from returned object*
>
> $res.data #dataset containing the datatables returned by selects
>
> $res.outputparams.ID   #output parameter ID (uniqueidentifier)

The function:

```
function exec-storedprocedure($storedProcName,  
        [hashtable] $parameters=@{},
        [hashtable] $outparams=@{},
        $conn,[switch]$help){ 

        function put-outputparameters($cmd, $outparams){
            foreach($outp in $outparams.Keys){
                $cmd.Parameters.Add("@$outp", (get-paramtype $outparams[$outp])).Direction=[System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
            }
        }
        function get-outputparameters($cmd,$outparams){
            foreach($p in $cmd.Parameters){
                if ($p.Direction -eq [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output){
                $outparams[$p.ParameterName.Replace("@","")]=$p.Value
                }
            }
        }

        function get-paramtype($typename,[switch]$help){
            switch ($typename){
                'uniqueidentifier' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::UniqueIdentifier}
                'int' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int}
                'xml' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Xml}
                'nvarchar' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarchar}
                default {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Varchar}
            }
        }
        if ($help){
            $msg = @"
    Execute a sql statement.  Parameters are allowed.  
    Input parameters should be a dictionary of parameter names and values.
    Output parameters should be a dictionary of parameter names and types.
    Return value will usually be a list of datarows. 

    Usage: exec-query sql [inputparameters] [outputparameters] [conn] [-help]
    "@
            Write-Host $msg
            return
        }
        $close=($conn.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]'Closed')
        if ($close) {
           $conn.Open()
        }

        $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
        $cmd.CommandType=[System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'
        $cmd.CommandText=$storedProcName
        foreach($p in $parameters.Keys){
            $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$p",[string]$parameters[$p]).Direction=
                  [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
        }

        put-outputparameters $cmd $outparams
        $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
        $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
        [Void]$da.fill($ds)
        if ($close) {
           $conn.Close()
        }
        get-outputparameters $cmd $outparams

        return @{data=$ds;outputparams=$outparams}
    }
```

Comment: On NVARCHAR output variables you must specify Size property, so code as shown above will cause on error.

Comment: what does the code do?

Comment: For NVARCHAR output variables try swapping the inner function "put-outputparameters" for the following. As yonsk says, the parameter size must be set to something other than zero to receive text: function put-outputparameters($cmd, $outparams){
   #newline-here foreach($outp in $outparams.Keys){ #newline-here 
        $par = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@$outp", (get-paramtype $outparams[$outp])) #newline-here
        $par.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output #newline-here
        $par.Size = 4000 #newline-here
        $cmd.Parameters.Add($par)
    } 
}

Answer (score 8):

Here is a function I use to execute sql commands. You just have to change $sqlCommand.CommandText to the name of your sproc and $SqlCommand.CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure.

```
function execute-Sql{
    param($server, $db, $sql )
    $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = 'server=' + $server + ';integrated security=TRUE;database=' + $db 
    $sqlConnection.Open()
    $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
    $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
    $sqlCommand.CommandText= $sql
    $text = $sql.Substring(0, 50)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Executing SQL" -Status "Executing SQL => $text..."
    Write-Host "Executing SQL => $text..."
    $result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $sqlConnection.Close()
}
```

Comment: What about `$sqlCommand.Dispose()` and `$sqlConnection.Dispose()`

Answer (score 3):

Use sqlcmd instead of osql if it's a 2005 database

Comment: This would work (and is a great simple solution) if you have the tools installed on the machine running the script. Otherwise, using .NET's System.Data.SqlClient seems necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Consider calling osql.exe (the command line tool for SQL Server) passing as parameter a text file written for each line with the call to the stored procedure.

SQL Server provides some assemblies that could be of use with the name SMO that have seamless integration with PowerShell. Here is an article on that.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3696731

There are API methods to execute stored procedures that I think are worth being investigated. Here a startup example:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29974894/smo-running-a-stored-pro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I include `invoke-sqlcmd2.ps1` and `write-datatable.ps1` from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/01/use-powershell-to-collect-server-data-and-write-to-sql.aspx.  Calls to run SQL commands take the form: 
`Invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance "<sql-server>" -Database <DB> -Query "truncate table <table>"` 
An example of writing the contents of DataTable variables to a SQL table looks like: 
`$logs = (get-item SQLSERVER:\sql\<server_path>).ReadErrorLog()
Write-DataTable -ServerInstance "<sql-server>" -Database "<DB>" -TableName "<table>" -Data $logs`
 I find these useful when doing SQL Server database-related PowerShell scripts as the resulting scripts are clean and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Adds `CommandType` and `Parameters` to @Santiago Cepas' answer:

```
function Execute-Stored-Procedure
{
    param($server, $db, $spname)
    $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = 'server=' + $server + ';integrated security=TRUE;database=' + $db 
    $sqlConnection.Open()
    $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 120
    $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
    $sqlCommand.CommandType= [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    # If you have paramters, add them like this:
    # $sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", "$param") | Out-Null
    $sqlCommand.CommandText= $spname
    $text = $spname.Substring(0, 50)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Executing Stored Procedure" -Status "Executing SQL => $text..."
    Write-Host "Executing Stored Procedure => $text..."
    $result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $sqlConnection.Close()
}


# Call like this:
Execute-Stored-Procedure -server "enter-server-name-here" -db "enter-db-name-here" -spname "enter-sp-name-here"
```

Answer (score 0):

I added timeout and show how to reader a scalar or get results using a reader

```
function exec-query( $storedProcName,$parameters=@{},$conn,$timeout=60){
 
 $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

 $cmd.CommandType=[System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'
 $cmd.Connection=$conn
 $cmd.CommandText=$storedProcName
 $cmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout
 foreach($p in $parameters.Keys){
  [Void] $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$p",$parameters[$p])
 }
  
 #$id=$cmd.ExecuteScalar()
 $adapter=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
 $dataset=New-Object system.Data.DataSet

 $adapter.fill($dataset) | Out-Null

    #$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    #$results = @()
    #while ($reader.Read())
    #{
    #    write-host "reached" -ForegroundColor Green
    #}

 return $dataSet.Tables[0]
}
```