# Simple task: Connect to database, execute a stored procedure, disconnect

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, procedure

I don't necessarily need to pass the stored procedures any variables from my VBScript, I just need to run the stored procedure on the server. I haven't been able to find any clear examples of how to do this—just a lot of people explaining how to pass a variable from a SP back to a VBScript.

Any help would be so appreciated! It looks like I'll have to open a connection, then send the command to execute the stored procedure, then close the connection, but I'm a bit lost about how to do this from a VBscript.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, a friendly tip, saying "M$" will actually make many of the people that *could* answer your question just turn away from it. Your opinions with Microsoft nonwithstanding, airing them out in the open might not give you the real benefits of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use the [`ADODB.Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681519%28VS.85%29.aspx) object from VbScript

check this sample

```vb
Dim sServer, sConn, oConn, sDatabaseName, sUser, sPassword
sDatabaseName="test"
sServer="localhost"
sUser="sa"
sPassword="yourpassword"
sConn="provider=sqloledb;data source=" & sServer & ";initial catalog=" & sDatabaseName

Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConn.Open sConn, sUser, sPassword
oConn.Execute "exec sp_help"

WScript.Echo "executed"
oConn.Close
Set oConn = Nothing
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method like this:

```vb
Public Sub ExecuteSql( sqlString )
    Dim oConn
    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open connectionString
    oConn.Execute( CStr(sqlString) )
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note**: This routine assumes that the SQL statement was built by the calling routine and properly escaped. In addition, `connectionString` is a constant that you store somewhere with the connection string to the db.

Example call:

```vb
Call ExecuteSql( "exec MyProc" )
```

Comment: Thomas, thank you for the reply. I'm also unsure of how to setup the connectionString, could you point me in the right direction? Thanks again!

Comment: @Joshua - Try www.connectionstrings.com.