# Execute a procedure on a specific day in Express Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, jobs

I have procedure which copies data from a client table a history table.

How I can do it automatically without involving user pressing button each month in some specific day?

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, so I cannot schedule a job using SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Express you can't use SQL Server Agent. However there are many alternatives, all of which you can schedule using [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744(v=ws.10).aspx) or [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx) depending on your operating system:

- [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997896/)
- [C# command line app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462447/how-to-run-an-sql-stored-procedure-through-c-sharp-at-a-specific-time)
- [batch file with SQLCMD](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/2931/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-command-line.html)
- [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83410/how-do-i-call-an-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-powershell)

All of these languages/tools (and many others) have the capacity to connect to SQL Server and execute a stored procedure. You can also try these Agent replacements:

- [SQLScheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx)
- [Express Agent](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/11/10/Express-Agent-for-SQL-Server-Express_3A00_-Jobs_2C00_-Jobs_2C00_-Jobs_2C00_-and-Mail.aspx)
- [Standalone SQL Agent (beta)](http://standalonesqlagent.codeplex.com/)

Here is an example using VBScript:

1. Open Notepad. Type the following code, replacing $tokens$ with your real values:

   ```
   s = "$your server/instance name$"
   db = "$your database name$"
   u = "$your SQL auth user ID$"
   p = "$your SQL auth password$"
   constr = "provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & s & ";Initial Catalog=" & s & _
            ";User ID=" & u & ";Password=" & p & ";Network=DBMSSOCN;"
   Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   conn.Open constr
   conn.Execute "EXEC dbo.$your procedure name$;"
   conn.close: set conn = nothing
   ```
2. Save this file as `c:\somewhere\ScheduledProcedure.vbs`
3. Open a command prompt and type the following (this will schedule this script to run on the 15th of every month at midnight), all on one line:

   ```
   schtasks /create /tn "some name" 
     /tr "wscript ""c:\somewhere\ScheduledProcedure.vbs""" 
     /sc monthly /d 15 /st 00:00
   ```

To see this task in your list of scheduled tasks (there are a lot, but it should be in the very first group):

```
schtasks /query
```

If you later want to delete it:

```
schtasks /delete /tn "some name" /F
```

Comment: Thanx! will look for something I know Visual studio has something like timer but not sure if it will work with asp.net

Comment: @Andrey what does any of this have to do with asp.net? If all you are trying to do is execute a stored procedure on a schedule, the fact that asp.net also uses that database is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: I have DB  and that Db connect to web site written on ASP.Net so i think i can call this procedure from .Net site by using timer.

Comment: I'll confess I have no idea what "timer" is, but if it relies on web site activity, I'm not sure that will work. What if nobody visits your web site at the right time?

Comment: I dont know :) problem is that  i may not  be able install some other software (SQLScheduler
Express Agent
Standalone SQL Agent (beta))on server which will host web page and db

Comment: Well (a) you don't have to install software. Windows already has AT and a task scheduler, and surely you can create something as simple as a VBScript. Also (b) you can schedule this from any machine that has reliable connectivity to the database server.

Comment: I don't know Visual Basic I know C# on entry level :( I think will have to make users click button every month, and wright data into table.

Comment: This is not difficult to do. I can assure you that you can do this without needing your users to click on anything.

Comment: I've added an example that shows how to execute a stored procedure using VBScript (you just need to plug in your specific variables), and then schedule it using `schtasks.exe`. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Express this is not possible - you will need to write a program which does this, then you can use the Windows task scheduler to execute the program.  The higher versions of SQL server include SQL Server Agent, which you can get to run things for you.

Comment: Thanx! will look for something