# Win task scheduler fails to run batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskscheduler

First of all, I did check hundreds of previous posts but I still have a problem. I have a T-SQL cursor. And I want to run this cursor every 5 minutes. In order to do that I've made a `*.bat` file (`sqlcmd -S DEAMON\SQLEXPRESS -i reminder_cursor.sql`) that runs it. Batch file and cursor file are both in the same folder (f.e. `sql_cursor`) and they both have the same name (f.e. `reminder_cursor.bat`, `reminder_cursor.sql`). In `taskschd` is:

General tab

- `When running the task, use the following user account: SYSTEM` don't want to see console window
- `run with the highest privileges` ticked
- `run whether user is logged on or not` ticked

Triggers tab

- `begin a task on a schedule`
- `Daily`
- `recur every 1 day`
- `Repeat task every 5 min for duration indefinitely`
- `Enabled` ticked

Actions tab

- `Action: start a program`
- `Program script` has exact path to the `bat` file
- `Start in (Optional):` has exact path to the folder where `bat` file is stored

When I run the same `bat` file manually, it works (every time). `Next run time` goes forward, but doesn't run batch.

Comment: You always have to use full paths to avoid problems (what is the default directory), especially when you've changed the user to another user (lots of things change). Full specified paths solves all problems. But why not just schedule sqlcmd rather than indirectly via a batch. Use full paths.

Comment: @Ken White, actually yes, I do. I have express edition and there is some sort of technical difficulties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103162/create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition

Comment: Fair enough. What @Noodles said, then. :-)

Comment: @Noodles I am. In `Action` tab, under `Program/script`, there is: `C:\Users\bartek\Documents\sql_cursor\reminder_cursor.bat` and under `Start in: C:\Users\bartek\Documents\sql_cursor`

Comment: I meant in your batchfile. Partial paths are an aid to typing interactively which you aren't doing. So full path to sqlcmd (as System's `path` variable is likely to be different to yours) and full path to the SQL file (as you are likely to be in a different default directory).

Comment: Didn't work. I have put: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd" -S DEMON\SQLEXPRESS -i C:\Users\bartek\Documents\sql_cursor\reminder_cursor.sql`, when I run batch file manually, it worked. Weird thing is that 3 days ago it was working. It looks like it stopped after computer restart. But I didn't do anything so have no idea what's wrong. Is there anything else I can check ?

Comment: Weird. I've changed user from `SYSTEM` to `demon\bartek` (my account), and it's working fine. Big drawback that console windows flicker every 5 minutes. 
EDIT:
I've put `SYSTEM` again, and it works too. Weird.

Comment: You can use `> c:\logfile` to read any errors.