# Pass SQL Variable to Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, variables, parameter-passing

I'm new to powershell, and I have a SQL stored procedure with some variables, and I want to know if it's possible to pass these variables to powershell to retrieve data from a source system. So i am using powershell to retrieve data. this powershell script will be executed by the same SQL SP. Before when it executes the powershell script it should use the variable that I Pass from the SP.

If this is possible, can anyone share an example how to pass a variable from sql to powershell?

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a SQL Server stored procedure from PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83410/how-do-i-call-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-from-powershell)