# How to run a stored procedure with parameters using bcp command against SQL Azure database

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, export-to-csv, bcp

I have a stored procedure which needs 2 mandatory input parameters. I need to run that stored procedure using `bcp` command and export the results to a csv file.

Note: the stored procedure is hosted in a SQL Azure instance for which I only have Azure AAD Authentication to my account. UserName and Password Auth is not allowed.

This `bcp` command is running fine to export data from a table. but I'm unable to execute stored procedure with 2 input parameters.

```
bcp DatabaseName.domain.MyTableName 
    out V:\MyDocuments\SourceType.csv 
    -U viratkohli@conco.com -S Servername.database.windows.net -G -c -t","
```

What I am expecting to work for stored procedure:

```
bcp DatabaseName.dbo.MyStoreProcedure 'Parameter1','Parameter2' 
    out V:\MyDocuments\SourceType.csv 
    -U viratkohli@conco.com -S Servername.database.windows.net -G -c -t","
```

or:

```
$SqlQuery = "DatabaseName.dbo.MyStoreProcedure 'Parameter1','Parameter2'"
bcp $SqlQuery out V:\MyDocuments\SourceType.csv -U viratkohli@conco.com -S Servername.database.windows.net -G -c -t","
```

Comment: In what way are you _unable to execute stored procedure with 2 input parameters._ ? Do you get an error ? Please post it. Your second syntax is most likely to work

Comment: Do you have to use BCP? Do you have the option of using `sqlcmd` or even better, `Powershell`?

Comment: When i run second bcp command, i get this error: A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options.

I'm doing this in PowerShell window only. Do you have any other sample script to print data from store procedure from Sql Azure Database using AAD authentication. once i can print in PowerShell, I can take care of rest.

Comment: Here's something on SO that shows how to call a SP with parameters and capture the output resultset https://stackoverflow.com/a/83791/1690193. Just be wary that the best library may have changed since this one but hopefully you get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a stored procedure with parameters using bcp command against SQL Azure database follow below command:

```bash
bcp "exec databas-ename.schema-name.SP-name 'Param1','Param2'" queryout "path of file" -S servername.database.windows.net -d dbname -U  username -G -c -t","
```

**Execution:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]